# Bind vector with list of vectors using cbind

Tags: r, list, cbind, do.call

I have an original `data.frame` and I would like to run `lapply` on certain columns then `cbind` the remaining columns with the results from the `lapply` operation.

See code below. I would ideally like `b` to contain the first `id` column from the `data.frame` with the results from the `lapply`. I am assuming my error is that my `list` argument to `cbind` contains a `list` of lists...the first argument to `list` is a vector, which could be handled, but the second argument is an actual `list` itself. Just wondering how to handle this.

Thanks!

```r
df <- data.frame(id = 1:10,
                 colB = 11:20,
                 colC = 21:30)

a <- lapply(df[,2:3],
            function(x) {x = 10 * x}
)

b <- do.call(cbind,
             list(df[,1],
                  a))
```

Created on 2019-02-16 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is subtle but important: for your code to work the way you want it you need

```
b <- do.call(cbind, list(df[1], a))
#                        ^^^^^
```

Result

```
b
#   id colB colC
#1   1  110  210
#2   2  120  220
#3   3  130  230
#4   4  140  240
#5   5  150  250
#6   6  160  260
#7   7  170  270
#8   8  180  280
#9   9  190  290
#10 10  200  300
```

The difference is that `df[1]` returns a `data.frame` while `df[,1]` returns a vector. `cbind` has a method for `data.frame`s which is what get's called in above case, but not in your case.

Comment: In general, will `do.call` treat a list element that is a list of `data.frames` - (so `do.call(cbind, list(df1, list_of_dfs))` where list_of_dfs is a list of dataframes; a list of lists in essences - as a series of dataframes? If `a` contained a plot or some other object, this may not work. In hindsight I may have over simplified my example... :)

Comment: @Prevost Yes and yes. You might ask a new question that includes this new requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can `cbind` only two `data.frame`s.

So, rewrite b as:

```
b <- cbind(df[1], as.data.frame(a))

> b
   id colB colC
1   1  110  210
2   2  120  220
3   3  130  230
4   4  140  240
5   5  150  250
6   6  160  260
7   7  170  270
8   8  180  280
9   9  190  290
10 10  200  300
```

Note that `df[1]` is used to retain `data.frame` status.

Comment: you can get away with `cbind(df[1], a)`

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `bind_cols()` from the `dplyr` package, which can also work with lists.

```
library(dplyr)
bind_cols(df[1], a)
```

`bind_cols()` expects all the arguments to be either data frames, named lists or named arguments. This is way you need to write `df[1]` instead of `df[, 1]` also in this case. However, if you explicitly name the argument, also `df[, 1]` will work:

```
bind_cols(id = df[, 1], a)
```